# Postgres - Single aggregation done with sequential scan, many aggregations index scan

Tags: performance, postgresql, indexing, aggregate-functions

I want to query a table and sum a column for all of the rows from the last day of the month.

Let's use the following table as an example:

```
CREATE TABLE example(dt date, value int, other1 int, other2 int, other3 int);
CREATE INDEX ON example (as_of);
```

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT dt, SUM(value)
FROM example
WHERE dt in (select date_trunc('month', d) + interval '1 month - 1 day'
             from generate_series('2012-01-01'::date, '2016-11-10'::date, interval '1 month') dates(d))
GROUP BY dt
```

If I look at the query plan for this I see that it's performing a sequential scan against the table:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYSE SELECT dt, SUM(value)
FROM example
WHERE dt in (select date_trunc('month', d) + interval '1 month - 1 day'
             from generate_series('2012-01-01'::date, '2016-11-10'::date, interval '1 month') dates(d))
GROUP BY dt

 GroupAggregate  (cost=825385.12..871490.30 rows=1536 width=12) (actual time=4323.887..6141.401 rows=56 loops=1)
   Group Key: example.Dt
   ->  Merge Join  (cost=825385.12..863846.28 rows=1525732 width=12) (actual time=4323.811..6118.514 rows=101102 loops=1)
         Merge Cond: (example.dt = ((date_trunc('month'::text, dates.d) + '1 mon -1 days'::interval)))
         ->  Sort  (cost=825312.64..832941.30 rows=3051464 width=12) (actual time=4323.585..5303.902 rows=3051464 loops=1)
               Sort Key: example.dt
               Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 77512kB
               ->  Seq Scan on example  (cost=0.00..392353.64 rows=3051464 width=12) (actual time=10.385..1748.592 rows=3051464 loops=1)
         ->  Sort  (cost=72.48..72.98 rows=200 width=8) (actual time=0.168..18.248 rows=101105 loops=1)
               Sort Key: ((date_trunc('month'::text, dates.d) + '1 mon -1 days'::interval))
               Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 27kB
               ->  Unique  (cost=59.84..64.84 rows=200 width=8) (actual time=0.108..0.143 rows=59 loops=1)
                     ->  Sort  (cost=59.84..62.34 rows=1000 width=8) (actual time=0.106..0.112 rows=59 loops=1)
                           Sort Key: ((date_trunc('month'::text, dates.d) + '1 mon -1 days'::interval))
                           Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 27kB
                           ->  Function Scan on generate_series dates  (cost=0.01..10.01 rows=1000 width=8) (actual time=0.042..0.097 rows=59 loops=1)
```

However, if I add  additional SUMs to the query then it decides to use the  index on `dt`:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYSE SELECT dt, SUM(value), SUM(other1), SUM(other2), SUM(other3)
FROM example
WHERE dt in (select date_trunc('month', d) + interval '1 month - 1 day'
             from generate_series('2012-01-01'::date, '2016-11-10'::date, interval '1 month') dates(d))
GROUP BY dt

HashAggregate  (cost=1005765.17..1005780.53 rows=1536 width=61) (actual time=225.249..225.276 rows=56 loops=1)
   Group Key: l.as_of
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=60.27..975250.53 rows=1525732 width=61) (actual time=0.141..173.853 rows=101102 loops=1)
         ->  Unique  (cost=59.84..64.84 rows=200 width=8) (actual time=0.100..0.192 rows=59 loops=1)
               ->  Sort  (cost=59.84..62.34 rows=1000 width=8) (actual time=0.099..0.125 rows=59 loops=1)
                     Sort Key: ((date_trunc('month'::text, dates.d) + '1 mon -1 days'::interval))
                     Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 27kB
                     ->  Function Scan on generate_series dates  (cost=0.01..10.01 rows=1000 width=8) (actual time=0.031..0.080 rows=59 loops=1)
         ->  Index Scan using dashboard_loanhistory_95daa586 on dashboard_loanhistory l  (cost=0.43..4856.06 rows=1987 width=61) (actual time=0.025..1.579 rows=1714 loops=59)
               Index Cond: (as_of = (date_trunc('month'::text, dates.d) + '1 mon -1 days'::interval))
 Planning time: 0.228 ms
 Execution time: 225.379 ms
```

What's going on here? I want the original query to run using the index on `dt`, I would rather not add additional aggregations to the query unnecessarily.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, done (there may be slight differences between my illustrative example and the query plans I provided but I believe they are, at least, similar enough for these purposes) and, to be clear, the same query just with extra SUMs on other columns does use the index

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name my bad, fixed

Comment: The real problem is the usage of `generate_series()`. The planner has no estimate of the destribution, so it always assumes 1000. Maybe should find a better way to find the last day of the month, such as: `WHERE date_trunc('month', dt) <> date_trunc('month', dt+ '1 day'::interval)`

Comment: @joop still does a sequential scan with the WHERE condition you proposed

Comment: Does it work better if you join against `generate_series()`?

Comment: Try to use `(select ... from generate_series...)` as CTE.

Comment: Putting the *last day of the month* generate_series() into a temp table still gives a seq scan, even if the temp table is unique on dt. I Guess the date index is barely usable with the scattered sparse dates ( ~3% of the records) Pre-aggregation *might* help. Or a conditional index on `date_trunc('month', dt) <> date_trunc('month', dt+ '1 day'::interval)` on the base table (Yuck!)

Answer (score 0):

This is based on comments from the question, particularly @joops answer. It's somewhat of a hack as it requires another index - I really don't understand why the query planner won't use the one on `dt` here but this works ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

I added a partial index on the `dt` column, restricting it to only those days which could possibly be the last day of a month:

```
CREATE INDEX ON example (dt) WHERE date_part('day', dt) IN (28, 29, 30, 31);
```

Then I altered my query to include a predicate on the day of the month being in that range:

```
SELECT dt, SUM(value)
FROM example
WHERE date_part('day', dt) IN (28, 29, 30, 31) AND
      dt IN (select date_trunc('month', d) + interval '1 month - 1 day' from generate_series('2012-01-01'::date, '2016-11-10'::date, interval '1 month') dates(d));
```